# Which database and engine should I use for a chat messages table

Tags: database, performance, database-design, chat, livechat

For a chat messages table, which has many parallel writes and many more parallel reads per second, which database and engine is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

To take decision, non-functional requirements & HW should be reviewed:

- How many chats? 1K? 1M?
- How many concurrent users?
- Infinite history?
- CPU? IO? RAM?

To be honest, I prefer PostgreSQL. It's scalable database, proven by time. :)